# Drag and drop in angular js for IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, drag-and-drop

I am using angular-file-upload directive to implement a file upload functionality with drag & drop. But it seems drag & drop works  only in HTML5 browsers.

Is there any way to support Drag & drop in IE8 along with other html5 browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Not with pure javascript + html. You would need to implement something with flash.

Comment: Is there any reference available to use?